# When an isometry is a hypercube symmetry?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra

Suppose that sequences $v_1,\ldots,v_m\in \{-1,+1\}^n$ and $u_1,\ldots,u_m\in \{-1,+1\}^n$ are isometric in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. $u_j=Qv_j$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$. What is the largest $m$ such that $Q$ is not an integer orthogonal matrix, i.e. one of the $2^n n!$ symmetries of the hypercube? In other words, what is the largest $m$ such that for some such isometric sequences $(u_j)$ and $(v_j)$ in $\{-1,+1\}^n$ there is no integer orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $u_j=Qv_j$?

Comment: You might first ask what's the smallest $n$ for which
this is possible at all.  An upper bound is $16$, because
there is more than one equivalence class of Hadamard matrices of order $16$.
It seems a plausible guess that the optimum for all feasible $n$ 
(or maybe all sufficiently large $n$) will be obtained
by starting from some small example, with parameters $(n_0, m_0)$, 
and forming a family of examples with parameters $(n, 2^{n-n_0} m_0)$ 
for each $n \geq n_0$ by extending $\{u_j\}$ and $\{v_j\}$ with all possible $\pm 1$ sequences 
of length $n-n_0$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, I would accept your example as an answer, since this is more or less what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks; first let me think about this a bit more ---
I think I can bring  $n_0$ down to $7$
(which will also increase the largest possible $m$).